# Opentripplanner Graph.obj file not found error

Tags: graph, leaflet, openstreetmap, opentripplanner

Trying to run the opentripplanner and using the Graph.obj to run it for a country.

But whenever trying to run the server it is giving the filenotfound exception at location /otp/Graph.obj although i have put the Graph.obj in the same location.

Stacktrace while running the server is :

Graph file not found or not openable for routerId '' under file:/otp
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /otp/Graph.obj (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:101)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)

Comment: Please add how you proceeded with the setup etc. so we can help.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem trying to run OTP.

**First problem**: the routerId is missing

**Second problem**: the default directory is /var/otp/graph and OTP seems to search the graph under /var/otp/graph/{routerId}

**Third problem** (may not be yours): I tried to run OTP in Cygwin (Windows) and probably there was some trouble with the slashes/backslashes, so I decided to copy the graph under a "../gtfs/gurgaon"

**Solution**:

Step 1) create a subdirectory like "/var/otp/graph/gurgaon" and copied Graph.obj over there

Step 2) run something like: *$ java -jar target/otp.jar --router gurgaon --graphs ../gtfs --server*

It worked like a charm for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: java -Xmx5G -jar target/otp-0.20.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar --build **path your gtfs and osm.pbf files** --inMemory

It worked perfect for me.